# how to add the value of checkbox in div and tirm/slice if the length of value reached its max length

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, checkbox

am trying to add keep on text through checkbox to certain limit. assume am having max character to 30 (with space). then user should not go beyond 30. for that i write like below

(note: this question was already asked but not clearly)

```js
clickCheck(appendVal, checked): void {
  if (checked) {
    if (this.baseName.length > 30) {
      this.baseName.substr(0, 30);
    } else {
      this.locationName = this.locationName + '' + appendVal;
      this.baseName = this.locationName + ":" + this.personName;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="displayInlineBlock  wdh100p">
  <input type="checkbox" value="this cannot be delivered in that location" (change)="clickCheck($event.target.getAttribute('appendVal'), $event.target.checked)">
  <label>add this text</label>
</div>
```

the value of checkbox ll reflect in immediate div

thanks for jumping into this and many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checked) {   
    this.locationName = this.locationName + '' + appendVal;
    this.baseName = this.locationName + ":" + this.personName;  

    if( this.baseName.length > 30){
        this.baseName = this.baseName.substr(0, 30);
    }
}
```

add what to want to your string and just trim it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`this.baseName.substr(0, 30);` does not directly change the value of `this.baseName`. The `substr()` function returns a string value. You need to assign that back to `this.baseName` if you want to use that value:

```
this.baseName = this.baseName.substr(0, 30);
```